# How can I override A-Frame CSS in an app built using create-react-app?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, create-react-app, aframe

I'm building a mobile app with 2D & 3D elements.

2D elements use React, and I'm using create-react-app for the build/bundling etc.

3D elements use A-Frame.

For iOS, I need to obtain device orientation permissions, and I'm doing this using the standard A-Frame component: https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/device-orientation-permission-ui.html

However I want to change the appearance of the modal, by specifying my own CSS (as suggested on that page).

I have a problem that appears only in my *production* build.

I've written the CSS overrides that I want in my App.css.  I build my production JS and CSS files.

They are included in index.html like this (inside the `<head>`)

```
<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.6b739253.js"></script>
<link href="/static/css/main.8198a130.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, on initialization, A-Frame adds its own CSS files to the end of the HTML header:

```
<style type="text/css" data-href="src/style/aframe.css">
...CSS here...
</style>
```

Because the A-Frame CSS appears at the end of the HTML header, it takes priority over my custom CSS, and I end up with the A-Frame styling for the modal, rather than my custom styling.

I've come up with *a* solution for this, but I think there's got to be a better one...

My solution: the following code at the top of my top-level React component, which explicitly removes the aframe.css styles from the HTML (I've also added the A-Frame styles that I *don't* want to override directly in my App.css, where I can have full control over what I do & don't include).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];

    for (var ii = 0; ii < head.children.length; ii++) {
      const child = head.children[ii];
      if (child.attributes['data-href'] && 
          child.attributes['data-href'].nodeValue === "src/style/aframe.css") {
        head.removeChild(child);
      }
    }
  }, [])
```

I'm looking for a better solution, where I don't have to duplicate large chunks of aframe.css in my own CSS file, and I can simply have the two CSS files loaded, but prioritized in a different order.

Ideally that solution would not require me to eject from create-react-app, which I have managed to avoid needing to do so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in fact a simple solution here.

A CSS specifier that specifies an element selector + a class selector is *more specific* than a specifier that specifies a class selector only.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

So the following CSS...

```
button.a-dialog-allow-button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

will be more specific (and hence take precedence over) the A-Frame defaults which look like this:

```
.a-dialog-allow-button {
  background-color: #00ceff;
}
```

Similarly you can override `.a-modal` with `div.a-modal`, `.a-dialog` with `div.a-dialog` etc.

One thing to watch out for (this threw me when testing this)... Not all A-Frame modals use the `a-modal` and `a-dialog` classes.

There are various other classes, used for specific modals - e.g. `a-enter-vr-modal` and `a-orientation-modal` (used for portrait / landscape orientation, rather than for device orientation permisions).

So just if you see an A-Frame modal, and your changes don't seem to have worked, it may be because it is using a different set of modal classes from the ones you changed.  Check the class names carefully!